# Mongoose Schemas Object ID Type Value return?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to retrieve a value with my schemas directed at another collection in the db:

```
_id: 61b248b0cd79df2124dcf283
name: "david"
email: "email@gmail.com"
dogRaces: 61a22138fdb728445ef9a067 (points to oid in another collection: {name: "name"})
expert: 61a2255b0f5aeabad0e3785b (points to oid in another collection: {name: "name"})
location: 61b248b0cd79df2124dcf282 (points to oid in another collection: {name: "name"})
```

In the frontend when I retrieve the information, the values are presented as the oid's and not the names inside the documents.

how can I retrieve my information correctly using nodejs?

here is my mongoose schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const trainerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type:String,
        required: true,
    },

    email: {
        type:String,
        required:true,
    },

    registrationDate: {
        type:Date,
        default: Date.now,
    },

    dogRaces: {
        type:mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref:"DogRace"
    },

    expert: {
        type:mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref:"Expert"
    },

    location: {
        type:mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref:"City"
    },

})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Trainer', trainerSchema);
```

my njs code:

```
async function getTrainer(req,res,next) {
    let trainer

    try {
        trainer = await Trainer.findById(req.params.id)
        .populate('dogRaces')
        .populate('expert')
        .populate('location');

        if (trainer == null) {
            return res.status(404).json({message: 'Cannot find trainer'});
        }
    } 
    catch(err) {
        return res.status(500).json({message: err.message});
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: That's very simple, you are getting ObjectIDs because you are storing and sending the ObjectIDs if you want the values that are meaningful for the user on the front-end side you should generate them on the back-end application and send it to the user

Comment: just some tips for solving the problem

Answer (score 1):

Using mongoose this is pretty straightforward through [.populate()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html). So in your case, it'd look something like:

```
const trainer = await Trainer.findOne({...})
.populate('dogRaces')
.populate('expert')
.populate('location');
```

Comment: I'm using in my code in Trainer.findById({...}), and it's not populating at all, still gives me the same oids as before. maybe thats the problem?

Comment: Edit your question and add your code please..

Comment: added it on my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Edit trainerSchema like :

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const DogRace = require('../yourentitypath/DogRace')
const Expert = require('../yourentitypath/Expert')
const City = require('../yourentitypath/City')

const trainerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type:String,
        required: true,
    },

    email: {
        type:String,
        required:true,
    },

    registrationDate: {
        type:Date,
        default: Date.now,
    },

    dogRaces: {
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:"DogRace"
    },

    expert: {
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:"Expert"
    },

    location: {
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:"City"
    },

})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Trainer', trainerSchema);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).